# Ruby on Rails Active record object

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have a User model and having has_many associations with Note model.
Getting the records in an array format. I have to show content(column of note model) only.
So, Fetching data using:

```
 @user.notes.pluck(:content).
```

It is giving like this.

```
["Testing Notes123", "Testing Notes12345"].
```

In UI I want to display like this:

```
  Testing Notes123
  Testing Notes12345
```

Could someone please help me to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the "UI" do you mean a web page? That would involve a controller and a view. If you're just talking about the console, then this should do it:

```
notes = @user.notes.pluck(:content)
notes.each do |note|
  puts note
end
```

Or:

```
notes = @user.notes.pluck(:content)
puts notes.join("\n")
```

Comment: I was looking for the last one. Thanks!